# CakePHP 3 Routing: How to route controller basis

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-routing, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp 3. I want to hide `frontends` controller in url.

My Routes config:

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'frontends'));
```

And I want to refer all function to `bloggers` controller when url start as `www.example.com/bloggers`

```
Router::connect('/bloggers/:action', array('controller' => 'bloggers'));
```

But `www.example.com/bloggers` also refers to frontends Controller's index function. It should refer to bloggers Controller's index function. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the order of your routing

First write this

```
Router::connect('/bloggers/:action', array('controller' => 'bloggers'));
```

and then this one

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'frontends'));
```